# Fullcalendar change entire background color for calendar

Tags: jquery, html, css, calendar, fullcalendar

I simply need to take my rendered Fullcalendar div and change the background from plain white to a dark grey. I'd also like to change the color of text for the dates to white. I'm trying to put this calendar on a darkly themed page.

The documentation is crammed full of how to accomplish this on specific events, specific days, single cells etc. but I haven't found a universal "switch" to flip in the CSS that changes the entire calendar's background color. Been changing every value to lime green in the CSS and pulling my hair out to no affect.

Hoping there is a simple answer!

Comment: Can you provide your HTML and CSS of the problematic section?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your css as I can't see the code to modify for you, but if you are changing a div for the calender it should just be a simple matter of adding in the background color, the same way you have changed the background of the page.

Your CSS should look like this;

```
#calendar
{
//* various CSS styles to make calendar
background-color: #A0A8A0;
}
```

That should give you the background you want if you add in the colour as long as you have a universal div for the calendar. If this doesn't work please paste the code relevant to the calendar.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if I can turn this into a fiddle as it seems that my question isn't as straightforward as I hoped! I already changed the background-color tag in the style directly on the div itself. The calendar is being rendered as a table on top of the div and the cells themselves are not transparent (or something...). I can change the background color but it does not impact the calendar unfortunately.

Comment: If you're not getting it transparent, you can always try adding in something like     background-transparent; in css. Difficult to see without the code, but good luck!

Comment: Yeah I'm working on a fiddle but can't seem to get it to render :P Me and my fat fingers [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcm9mx4p/)

Comment: Ok thanks for the help! I can't get the thing to render but I've figured it out... No easy fix. I needed to use the element inspector to find the exact ids/classes/element names of the stuff I wanted to change. I then modified the fullcalendar.css file to incorporate my changes. Slow, but it got the job done!

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are a few items that need to be modified in the `fullcalendar.css` file if the entire background and label text is to be changed. The calendar renders a table over the div, so the table has to be changed.

Find the "table" section in the fullcalendar.css file.

Locate `.fc td` and add the following

- `background-color: #333 !important;`
- `color: #ffffff;`

Also added a new/separate style for `.fc th`

- `color: #ffffff`

And added one more style that finds all `.fc td` with a class of `other-month` in the name

That selector is `.fc td[class*="other-month"]` with the following styles specified:

- `color: #ffffff;`
- Still trying to determine how to change the background color of the `other-month` class so that it better blends with my page.

Comment: did you figure out how to change other month background?.

Comment: How change the border color of each cell ?

Answer (score 0):

For FullCalendar 5 using the timeGridWeek view this is what I've done.

```
#calendar .fc-view {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
#calendar  {
    --fc-page-bg-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

With the first style you can change the background of the calendar.

The second one is just in case that you have the stickyHeaderDates set to true.

This should work for all views as well as for multiple calendars in the same view.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the background on Days like this,
it works on v 5.10.1 and must customized on 6.1.10:

```
var containers = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-daygrid-day-frame');
  for (let i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
       
    if(containers[i].innerHTML.includes('fc-daygrid-event-harness'))
      {
         console.log(containers[i].innerHTML);
          containers[i].style.background = "red";
      }
    else
      {
        containers[i].style.background = "green";
      }
        
    }
```

[https://codepen](https://codepen.io/Wolfgang-Schorge/pen/WNmKwRN?editors=0010)